# How to skip multiple lines when reading from a file pointer in PHP

Tags: php, csv

I have a somewhat irregularly structured CSV file I'm reading with `fopen()` and `fgetcsv()`.  The first 5 lines are to be discarded.

Is there an efficient way to discard those 5 lines?  What I have now is:

```php
$fp = fopen($path,'r');
fgets($fp);fgets($fp);fgets($fp);fgets($fp);fgets($fp);
```

which gets the job done, but seems dirty.

Comment: With [SPLFileObj](https://www.php.net/manual/en/splfileobject.seek.php) you can do `seek` with line numbers.  Without it you have to know the byte values

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Do you mean seek()?

Comment: Yes - Seek.  with fseek you need the byte offset, which isn't workable.  it's pretty trivial though.  There is actually a trick with `$File->seek(PHP_INT_MAX); $end = $File->key(); $File->rewind()` that can give you the line total much faster then iterating through it.... :0}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So like this

```
 $CSV = new SplFileObject($file);
 $CSV->seek(5);
 $row = $CSV->fgetcsv();
```

Comment: Only a hint: There is a difference between `skip 5 text lines` (request of the OP) and `skip 5 table rows` offered here. Maybe the OP wants this.